# @nd time giving error,during TENSORFLOW execution

Tags: python, tensorflow

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.ones([10, 10]))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-bc8c707e6655> in <module>
----> 1 print(tf.ones([10, 10]))

AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'ones'
```

First time giving proper answer...but when executing after 5 minutes same COMMAND giving error.

Comment: That's could be due to changing in tensorflow version... could you print the tensorflow version? This can be done using `tf.__version__`

Comment: i checked ,    '2.0.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error can occur due to changes in tensorflow version... As I understood from your comment, you're using tensorflow 2.0 and to print the tensor values you need to use `tf.print` just like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.print(tf.ones([10, 10]))
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: do u have any idea about Django..that may i ask something...bcz due to some asking problem FORMATE ,i m not able to ask there...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any Django :(

Comment: ok thanks..no problem..i did from my self..again once...lot of thanks